# CakePHP3 Auth redirectURL route broken

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I have a controller with a particular method to login:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }

    // not logged
    $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect');

    }
}
```

and default route looks like

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

after user is logged in CakePHP throws an error

> Error: A route matching "/" could not be found.
>
> None of the currently connected routes match the provided parameters.
>   Add a matching route to config/routes.php

when IMO it should to redirect to the page (based on a related controller) from where login method was executed.

Login code is based on [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eASSNS1f3V4) tutorial.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue:

Please update the below lines in routes.php file

Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index']);

$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
```

});
Plugin::routes();

Please do create index() in users controller.
Let  me know if any issue.